# creating a dependency tree of C functions in Python

Tags: python, parsing, data-structures, graph-theory

I am trying to parse a C program using python and I need to find a way to achieve the graph of all of the functions that displays their dependencies. For example, if I have a program as such:

```
f1();
f2(){
 f1();
}
f3(){
 f1();
}
```

the graph would be:

```
f2   f3
|    /
|   /
f1
```

I want the graph to be presented as some form of data structure (eg. a tree not visually) does anyone have any suggestions?

edit: to clarify, the main issue is how I can do the parsing method.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a list of lists. Your example would translate to `[f1,[f2, f3]]`

Comment: how would u create that list while parsing? remember that the dependencies in a real file are more complicated than the example

Comment: Now that I think of it maybe a dict is better for this... So in the beginning you add the keys when you find them in the file `my_dict[f1]={}`. And then you should add the new function when you find it in the file `my_dict[f1][f2]=info_about_f2`. Does this make sense?